# 'pMod1' no matching overloaded function found (using implicit conversion) and function is not known

Tags: python, glsl

I wanted to try the Procedural 3D Engine. The code is correct, only I get:

"GLSL Compiler failed

fragment_shader

===============

ERROR: 0:727: 'pMod1' : no matching overloaded function found (using implicit conversion)

ERROR: 0:727: 'pMod1' : function is not known "

This code is connected to hg_sdf.glsl. But for some reason, this one does not work, although others work fine. Everything works fine without it.

Here is the code:

"

```
#version 330 core
#include hg_sdf.glsl
layout (location = 0) out vec4 fragColor;

uniform vec2 u_resolution;
uniform vec2 u_mouse;
uniform float u_time;

const float FOV = 1.0;
const int MAX_STEPS = 256;
const float MAX_DIST = 500;
const float EPSILON = 0.001;

float fDisplace(vec3 p) {
    pR(p.yz, sin(2.0 * u_time));
    return (sin(p.x + 4.0 * u_time) * sin(p.y + sin(2.0 * u_time)) * sin(p.z + 6.0 * u_time));
}

vec2 fOpUnionID(vec2 res1, vec2 res2) {
    return (res1.x < res2.x) ? res1 : res2;
}

vec2 fOpDifferenceID(vec2 res1, vec2 res2) {
    return (res1.x > -res2.x) ? res1 : vec2(-res2.x, res2.y);
}

vec2 fOpDifferenceColumnsID(vec2 res1, vec2 res2, float r, float n) {
    float dist = fOpDifferenceColumns(res1.x, res2.x, r, n);
    return (res1.x > -res2.x) ? vec2(dist, res1.y) : vec2(dist, res2.y);
}

vec2 fOpUnionStairsID(vec2 res1, vec2 res2, float r, float n) {
    float dist = fOpUnionStairs(res1.x, res2.x, r, n);
    return (res1.x < res2.x) ? vec2(dist, res1.y) : vec2(dist, res2.y);
}

vec2 fOpUnionChamferID(vec2 res1, vec2 res2, float r) {
    float dist = fOpUnionChamfer(res1.x, res2.x, r);
    return (res1.x < res2.x) ? vec2(dist, res1.y) : vec2(dist, res2.y);
}

vec2 map(vec3 p) {
    // plane
    float planeDist = fPlane(p, vec3(0, 1, 0), 14.0);
    float planeID = 2.0;
    vec2 plane = vec2(planeDist, planeID);
    // torus
    vec3 pt = p + 0.2;
    pt.y -= 8;
    pR(pt.yx, 4.0 * u_time);
    pR(pt.yz, 0.3 * u_time);
    float torusDist = fTorus(pt, 0.7, 16.0);
    float torusID = 5.0;
    vec2 torus = vec2(torusDist, torusID);
    // sphere
    vec3 ps = p + 0.2;
    ps.y -= 8;
    float sphereDist = fSphere(ps, 13.0 + fDisplace(p));
    float sphereID = 1.0;
    vec2 sphere = vec2(sphereDist, sphereID);
    // manipulation operators
    pMirrorOctant(p.xz, vec2(50, 50));
    p.x = -abs(p.x) + 20;
    pMod1(p.z, 15); #This is what causes the error
    // roof
    vec3 pr = p;
    pr.y -= 15.7;
    pR(pr.xy, 0.6);
    pr.x -= 18.0;
    float roofDist = fBox2Cheap(pr.xy, vec2(20, 0.5));
    float roofID = 4.0;
    vec2 roof = vec2(roofDist, roofID);
    // box
    float boxDist = fBoxCheap(p, vec3(3,9,4));
    float boxID = 3.0;
    vec2 box = vec2(boxDist, boxID);
    // cylinder
    vec3 pc = p;
    pc.y -= 9.0;
    float cylinderDist = fCylinder(pc.yxz, 4, 3);
    float cylinderID = 3.0;
    vec2 cylinder = vec2(cylinderDist, cylinderID);
    // wall
    float wallDist = fBox2Cheap(p.xy, vec2(1, 15));
    float wallID = 3.0;
    vec2 wall = vec2(wallDist, wallID);
    // result
    vec2 res;
//    res = wall;
    res = fOpUnionID(box, cylinder);
    res = fOpDifferenceColumnsID(wall, res, 0.6, 3.0);
    res = fOpUnionChamferID(res, roof, 0.6);
    res = fOpUnionStairsID(res, plane, 4.0, 5.0);
    res = fOpUnionID(res, sphere);
    res = fOpUnionID(res, torus);
    return res;
}

vec2 rayMarch(vec3 ro, vec3 rd) {
    vec2 hit, object;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_STEPS; i++) {
        vec3 p = ro + object.x * rd;
        hit = map(p);
        object.x += hit.x;
        object.y = hit.y;
        if (abs(hit.x) < EPSILON || object.x > MAX_DIST) break;
    }
    return object;
}

vec3 getNormal(vec3 p) {
    vec2 e = vec2(EPSILON, 0.0);
    vec3 n = vec3(map(p).x) - vec3(map(p - e.xyy).x, map(p - e.yxy).x, map(p - e.yyx).x);
    return normalize(n);
}

vec3 getLight(vec3 p, vec3 rd, vec3 color) {
    vec3 lightPos = vec3(10.0, 55.0, -20.0);
    vec3 L = normalize(lightPos - p);
    vec3 N = getNormal(p);
    vec3 V = -rd;
    vec3 R = reflect(-L, N);

    vec3 specColor = vec3(0.5);
    vec3 specular = specColor * pow(clamp(dot(R, V), 0.0, 1.0), 10.0);
    vec3 diffuse = color * clamp(dot(L, N), 0.0, 1.0);
    vec3 ambient = color * 0.05;
    vec3 fresnel = 0.25 * color * pow(1.0 + dot(rd, N), 3.0);

    // shadows
    float d = rayMarch(p + N * 0.02, normalize(lightPos)).x;
    if (d < length(lightPos - p)) return ambient + fresnel;

    return diffuse + ambient + specular + fresnel;
}

vec3 getMaterial(vec3 p, float id) {
    vec3 m;
    switch (int(id)) {
        case 1:
        m = vec3(0.9, 0.0, 0.0); break;
        case 2:
        m = vec3(0.2 + 0.4 * mod(floor(p.x) + floor(p.z), 2.0)); break;
        case 3:
        m = vec3(0.7, 0.8, 0.9); break;
        case 4:
        vec2 i = step(fract(0.5 * p.xz), vec2(1.0 / 10.0));
        m = ((1.0 - i.x) * (1.0 - i.y)) * vec3(0.37, 0.12, 0.0); break;
    }
    return m;
}

mat3 getCam(vec3 ro, vec3 lookAt) {
    vec3 camF = normalize(vec3(lookAt - ro));
    vec3 camR = normalize(cross(vec3(0, 1, 0), camF));
    vec3 camU = cross(camF, camR);
    return mat3(camR, camU, camF);
}

void mouseControl(inout vec3 ro) {
    vec2 m = u_mouse / u_resolution;
    pR(ro.yz, m.y * PI * 0.4 - 0.4);
    pR(ro.xz, m.x * TAU);
}

void render(inout vec3 col, in vec2 uv) {
    vec3 ro = vec3(36.0, 19.0, -36.0);
    mouseControl(ro);

    vec3 lookAt = vec3(0, 1, 0);
    vec3 rd = getCam(ro, lookAt) * normalize(vec3(uv, FOV));

    vec2 object = rayMarch(ro, rd);

    vec3 background = vec3(0.5, 0.8, 0.9);
    if (object.x < MAX_DIST) {
        vec3 p = ro + object.x * rd;
        vec3 material = getMaterial(p, object.y);
        col += getLight(p, rd, material);
        // fog
        col = mix(col, background, 1.0 - exp(-0.00002 * object.x * object.x));
    } else {
        col += background - max(0.9 * rd.y, 0.0);
    }
}

void main() {
    vec2 uv = (2.0 * gl_FragCoord.xy - u_resolution.xy) / u_resolution.y;

    vec3 col;
    render(col, uv);

    // gamma correction
    col = pow(col, vec3(0.4545));
    fragColor = vec4(col, 1.0);
}"
But it seems to me that this is the way to use it, since it is done more better.
```

Comment: Yes there is no `pMod1` function in your code. So what is the question?

Comment: the problem is that other modules work, but this one doesn't work. In hg_sf.everything is written in glsl, including pMod1.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue with trying this demo out.

The answer is that the pMod1 function expects floats for both the parameters, but that '15' there is, implicitly, an int. No pMod1 function exists that has a float as the first arg and an int as the second.

The solution is to change that '15' to '15.' so that const is implicitly a float instead.